# How to set a special class or id for a li that contain php code in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.6

According to this code :

```
@foreach($apps as $app)
<li><a>{{$app->name}}</a></li>
@endforeach
```

I have an app table in my database and Im fetching data from db to here .I want to show the above links details in a modal box so I need to have a specific id or class for each link generated by foreach loop above to open the modal and do others.

Answer (score 0):

To add class or id in li element with foreach

```
@foreach($apps as $app)
   <li class="someclassname_{{$app->id}}" id="someidname_{{$app->id}}"> 
       <a>
           {{$app->name}}
       </a>
   </li>
@endforeach
```

The result will look like this

```
<li class="someclassname_1" id="someidname_1" > </li> 
<li class="someclassname_2" id="someidname_2" > </li> 
<li class="someclassname_3" id="someidname_3" > </li>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: No it wont :). Better check that

Comment: That is a terrible idea.

Comment: If `{{$app->id}}` increments in the `id` it will also increment in the `class` and that is probably not a good idea

Comment: Looks fine to me, I don't know why you're calling it a terrible idea; he's using the app id which is defined in the database for each app entry